# How to restrict access to views in Codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Using Codeigniter I want to make my `home.php` restricted to only registered users but when I try following

`http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/application/views/home.php`

I get access to home.php(which is in views).
I thought that CI has some restriction for this type of request but its not.So now how can I solve this.

Should I do this in .htaccess?
`OR`
I should add `php` code at the top of `home.php` which will check for valid session data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application folder make .htaccess with this:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: @DeiFrom I used Deny from all to restrict access to assets but now even the registered user cannot see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316445/unable-to-access-assets-folder-in-codeigniter

Comment: I am using this method. It was there by default when I downloaded the CI. You need to make controller for this. Lets say: Controller user method home and there you will load the view with: `$this->load->view('home');`

Answer (score 2):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/

> For the best security, both the system and any application folders
>   should be placed above web root so that they are not directly
>   accessible via a browser. By default, .htaccess files are included in
>   each folder to help prevent direct access, but it is best to remove
>   them from public access entirely in case the web server configuration
>   changes or doesn't abide by the .htaccess.