# Unable to access assets folder in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My directory structure is as follows:

> -application
>   -system
>   -assets
>   --images
>   --downloads
>    --css
>   index.php

I created `assets` as suggested on `stackoverflow`,I wanted to restrict access to `downloads` so placed .htaccess file in `assets` folder with the following directive

`Deny from all`

now its protected but as `assets` has `css` files and those are also not accessible too.

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish should not be done with .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the htaccess file to downloads file

Comment: ok what if I want to give access to authorized users and you know this Deny from all restricts it for everyone.

Comment: Then I recommend you to make some controller called download where you can check session data and then force download the file